# Getting save feature to recognize dynamically created textboxes and tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some code which dynamically creates tabs and text boxes.  I am working on a save feature.  I have the form names saving, but I also need to save the content of the 4 textboxes in the tab.

tb.text is textbox 1.
tb1.text is textbox 2.
tb2.text is textbox 3.
tb3.text is textbox 4.

That being said, tb, tb1, tb2, and tb3 are available in the same button, but not available outside of the button click.  How would I get it so that I am able to access these .text textboxes outside of the button?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Would changing the above to public make any difference?  I have tried doing this and I still cannot get tb.text to be recognized outside of the buttonclick.

Comment: The `private` keyword defines the availability of the method to code outside the class.  It doesn't affect anything else.

Comment: Please tell me you're not dynamically creating textboxes inside a button click handler...

Comment: Yes, I am.  Why is that?

Comment: @Sorpigal, He wants to create some text boxes in response to a button click.  What is the issue?

Comment: @Inuyasha: The problem is that it's ASP.NET. Controls added to the page after OnInit are problematic.

Comment: @Sorpigal, ah yes, indeed, I didn't notice the tag.

Answer (score 2):

Read up on how ASP.NET dynamic controls work in [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx).

Your textboxes are not being recreated after a postback.

You can either get around this with a panel which always contains your textbox, you can then set the visible property to hide or show it on postback as needed, or if that really won't work for you I would suggest using [DynamicControlsPlaceholder](http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx) - though it is probably best used sparingly.